# android imageview set gif but flashing black

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, gif, android-glide

I use Glide to load gif into my custom dialog,

```
Glide.with(Home_Activity.this)
                .load(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brushgo-67813.appspot.com/o/image%2Ffirework.gif?alt=media&token=c3d69e19-6be0-415e-86ff-7aeed07f3c51"))
                .dontAnimate()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.firework16)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(fireworkArray[i]);
```

but when I run my application, my `ImageView` sometimes flashing black,

just like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zZKoXQ7UOY&feature=youtu.be).

But I tried to change my gif, and I also checked my gif, but it looks not my gif's question,

does anyone face the same problem?

And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

Glide 4.0.0-RC0

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).asGif().into(imageView);
```

Comment: It's work!!,but in Glide 4.0.0, how can I use dontanimate()?

Comment: is your image view still flickering?

Comment: No, I solve this problam,I change my Glide 3.7.0 into 4.1.0
But I have another question need to use placeholder and dontanimate

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071230/use-glide-load-into-imageview-but-delay

But in this glide version,they doesn't work:(

Comment: your issue is with slow loading of the glide image ?

Comment: Yap,when I load image,it needs some times

Comment: see the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071230/use-glide-load-into-imageview-but-delay please reply if it works